# AJAX filter posts by year

Tags: posts, wp-query, ajax

So I have a HTML select form which allows users to choose years such as 2017 , 2018 etc

Hence, what i want this to achieve is when user selects 2017 , the posts from 2017 will be loaded on the page.

My process thought was to use AJAX along with WP_QUERY to accomplish this.

However, the error i am receiving is ERROR 400 BAD REQUEST.

Thus any help given will be greatly appreciated.

**Front end**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter>
   <select id="year"></select>
</form>
```

*JS ajax request*

```
$.ajax({
    url : filter.attr('action') ,
    data : filter.serialize() ,
    type : filter.attr('method') ,
    success : function (response)
    {
        console.log(response)
    } ,
    error : function (request , status , error)
    {
        console.log(request.responseText)
        console.log(error)
    } ,
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } ,
    datatype : 'xml'
}).done(function () {
    console.log('ajax completed')
})
```

**functions.php**

```
function filter_post_asb
{
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 43 ,
    'year' => $_POST['year']
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query -> have_posts()) :
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <select id="year"></select>
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/logo.png" >
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_permalink();?></h2>
            <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile ; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
endif;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_post_asb');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_post_asb');
```

Once again, thank you very much for all the input given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by change appropriate code:

**Front end**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter>
   <select name="year"></select>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filter" />
</form>
```

*JS ajax request*

```
$.ajax({
    url : filter.attr('action') ,
    data : filter.serialize() ,
    type : filter.attr('method') ,
    success : function (response)
    {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error : function (request , status , error)
    {
        console.log(request.responseText)
        console.log(error)
    }
}).done(function () {
    console.log('ajax completed')
})
```

**functions.php**

```
function filter_post_asb {

    ob_start()

    $args = array(
       'cat' => 43,
       'year' => $_POST['year']
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $query -> have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="container">
    <select id="year"></select>
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/logo.png" >
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_permalink();?></h2>
            <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile ; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <?php
   endif;
   echo ob_get_clean();

   // OR
   // $html = ob_get_clean();
   // echo json_encode( array( 'html' => $html ) );
   exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_post_asb');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_post_asb');
```

Comment: Thank you very much good Sir, I tried to upvote your answer but I couldn't because i haven't fullfilled the reputation requirement.

I am not too sure, if I can ask you this question here, Please forgive me if i am not suppose to ask it here. SO here is the question,the ajax is working fine as of now, however wp_query is not working as in the functions.php. I am not too sure if I am calling it correctly. Are you able to advise on this? thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use WP_Query in ajax, try removing spaces `$query->have_posts()`, this may be issue. also if not working provide the error what you are getting there.

Comment: thank you and sorry for the late reply . I was away due to a knee injury. So the current update of this issue is that i am able to load it via ajax, thanks to you. However, when functions.php loads the the_content() , it spits out html code like this http://prntscr.com/mjy2vj , i suspect this is probably due to posts was created by a plugin call divi. are you able to advise on this? thank you

Comment: just change the_content like: `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`

Comment: actually i did do that in my functions.php file 

I have inserted this $content = apply_filters( 'the_content' , wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content())); but still it spits out the html.

Comment: try without 'wp_strip_all_tags', if still remains same, then maybe issue with your builder. also if you are using cache, please clear the cache.

Comment: I did that, but still spits out html content, let me ask around here, if still cannot, i will check with the divi builder dev, thank you very much Sir, you have been very helpful, once again thank you

Comment: and I finally can upvote your answer, so i am gonna do that :)